# Button:hover not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, hover

I haveing the problem that the hover is not working in Firefox! It is working in Chrome, IE 9, IE 8 and IE 7. Does somewone know this problem and how to fix it?

**The CSS**:
`.row button span:hover {
    background-position : left bottom;
    border : 1px solid #2b2b2b;
}`

**The HTML**:
`<button type="submit"><span>Button</span></button>`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like the hover event isn't getting fed down to the span.

Try selecting `button:hover span` instead of `button span:hover`

Here's a JSFiddle that works okay by doing the above: http://jsfiddle.net/3j7G5/

Comment: Spudley your are good! :)...Stupid of me i have not thinging off that!

Comment: Indeed, the child elements of the button are not candidates for mouse events. There's even a comment in the appropriate file: "we don't want our children to get any events."

Comment: @Neil do you have a source for that?

Comment: @TylerH http://bonsai.mozilla.org/cvsblame.cgi?file=mozilla/layout/forms/nsHTMLButtonControlFrame.cpp&rev=3.55&root=/cvsroot#307 so it's been like that in Gecko for over 15 years.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Assuming you're using Windows 7, that's the Windows button hover colour you're seeing there.