# Button element in FF not applying hover background color on child elements

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I need to use semantic markup for an SEO code-friendly product using the button element, and schema attributes. So I used "span" elements to separate out the individual items. I did set the items I want to hover with background effects as display:block.

Works in: Chrome, Safari on MAC. Chrome and IE on Windows.
Does not work in FF in Mac or Windows: In FF, the background color hover effects are not being applied. Wat?

Cannot use "ul, ol, li, div" or anything else that is not a "phrasing content" element inside button elements, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button.

[Click here for phrasing content allowed.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content)

Cannot use images. Cannot use Javascript.

**EDIT:** *"button:hover" and "button:hover .class" styles work fine. "button .class:hover" does NOT work in FF. I updated the fiddle to show what I expect on hover.*

**EDIT** verified as a problem here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1014203

**EDIT** bug filed with Mozilla here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=843003

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jbergloff/32jh2/

**HTML:**

```
<button class="product">
    <span class="offer">
        <span class="product-name">Product</span>
        <span class="product-price">$5.99</span>
    </span>
    <span class="product-features">
        <span class="list-item">HOVER ME</span>
        <span class="list-item">List Item 2</span>
        <span class="list-item">List Item 3</span>
    </span>
</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.product {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    background: green;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    min-width:150px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.product .offer {
    display: block;
    border: solid 1px green;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.product:hover .offer {
    border: solid 1px #FFF;
}
.product-name {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    display: block;
}
.product-price {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.product-features {
    display: block;
}
.product-features .list-item {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 2px;
    height:auto; /* in case a feature needs to be on two lines, don't cut off or hide the text */
}

/* WAT: this doesn't work in FF */
.product-features .list-item:hover {
    background: lightgreen;
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965810/buttonhover-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: The only solution to this if you wish to retain hover for both the parent as well as the children elements is to use `span` instead of `button` as the container.

Comment: @vikram-deshmukh: Thanks for your help, but doing that, would still require putting all of it into a `button` in order to submit the `form`. And putting it into the `button` again would prevent the `:hover` from working individually on the children. Works in other browsers, not FF...

Comment: If you only need the `button` to submit the form, then you can achieve that using `onclick` on the parent `span` or by using an `anchor` tag to contain all children elements and changing it's `href` attribute to instead submit the form. Let me know if you wish to see a demo of this. Hope this helps!

Comment: @VikramDeshmukh please read the description. It needs to be a button, and no Javascript allowed.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act), "Selectors [don't] define if the parent of an element that is ‘:active’ or ‘:hover’ is also in that state."

In your case, the parent element (`.product`) is already being hovered with a `:hover` pseudo-class (`.product:hover .offer`). That it works in other browsers seems to be an imperfect implementation of the specification.

Additionally, it seems that, in Firefox, children elements of the HTML5 `<button>` element are not valid candidates for hover events. This is a bug and I've submitted a bug report with Bugzilla. Until it gets fixed, it looks like there isn't a solution. Here is the bug report filed to be fixed: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=843003

Comment: I am trying to solve why the hover background color does not apply to the "list-item" child elements. I understand and do not expect the parent to inherit :hover. I do expect the child "list-item" to have :hover applied when the pointer is over it.

Comment: "button.product:hover" is not what I am trying to solve. "button.product .list-item:hover" is.

Comment: @jbergloff You misunderstand; `.product` is a parent of `.list-item`. You have a hover effect on `.product`. Therefore, your `.list-item` hover won't work, because hover is already being applied to the parent.

Comment: Yes `.product` is the parent of `.list-item`. And yes, `.product` already has it's own hover styles. `.list-item:hover` **should** work, as per the W3C spec you mentioned above. _"The :hover pseudo-class applies while the user designates an element with a pointing device, but does not necessarily activate it. "_ The `.list-item` is an element. The other browsers that allow it to work, are implementing it correctly. This may be a FF bug on the `button` element, where it doesn't seem to recognize that all children are elements that should have hover events tied to them as per the W3C spec.

Comment: I didn't mean to leave out the "thanks for your help". Sorry. I do understand the hierarchy, hopefully you understand that all elements should have a pseudo `:hover` applied when hovered over.

Comment: @jbergloff Updated my answer with another paragraph of information. Looks like you're out of luck until a future version of Firefox fixes this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple trick to make child of `button` tag which is sensitive to hover and click in FF - if you know the size of the child.

You can obtain it doing:

1. Wrap button with `<div style = "position : relative">` element
2. Make place for child of the button (e.g. increase `padding-right` of the button)
3. Create child in appriopriate place using `style = "position : absolute;"`

Enjoy your button with child sensitive to hover in FF and other browsers.

Example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/9tmsMMxFXpBPqQCbP8VW?p=preview