# Css button hover issue in chrome

Tags: css

I have faced a wired issue in chrome browser with button css. When I hover this button in chrome(not in firefox) its give unexpected effect.

here is current css:

```
input[type="button"], .button, button {
    font-size: 100%;
    transition: none !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    line-height: 17px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 3px solid #DDD;
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    color: #666;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}

input[type="button"]:hover, .button:hover, button:hover {
    border-color: #8E7EBF;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #8E7EBF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}

a, span, i {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
```

Comment: Please post some code and describe the problem and what the expected behavior should be.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: oops sorry. I have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

I think you must take a look on theses properties of CSS (line 1058 of theme.css) :

```
a:hover, span:hover, i:hover
```

You must used this synthax for better compatibility :

```
a:hover, button:hover span, button:hover i
```

You can see the similar problem here : [Button:hover not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965810/buttonhover-not-working-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

Hi Write this css in  your css file it will fix the problem

```
a:hover, span:hover, i:hover {
    -webkit-transition: initial;
    transition: initial;
}
```

Comment: this solves trans in effect. but trans out effect still the same

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue on chrome on hover btn class i fixed that adding this class to button

```
.btn-reset-transform:hover {
        -webkit-transition: none !important;
        -moz-transition: none !important;
        -ms-transition: none !important;
        -o-transition: none !important;
        transition: none !important;
        -webkit-transform: none !important;
        -moz-transform: none !important;
        -ms-transform: none !important;
        -o-transform: none !important;
        transform: none !important;
    }
```