# Hover doesn't work on Firefox when <i> is inside a button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I have a very simple Bootstrap button with a font-awesome icon inside it. I need to capture the hover event to change the color of the icon.
Works perfectly fine in IE and chrome but not on Firefox. I have tried many things including putting the `<i>` inside a span but nothing worked for Firefox.
I have also added a jQuery listener on the mouseEnter event just as a proof that no events are triggered.

Is this a bug in Firefox?
Is there a way around this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dft2nqqd/2/

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-default no-left-border current-location-button"  type="button">
<i class="fa fa-battery-full"></i>
</button>
```

CSS

```css
.fa-battery-full {
    font-size: 24px;
}

.fa-battery-full:hover {
    color:red;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".fa-battery-empty").mouseenter(function(){
   alert("Hover");
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, this appears to be a bug in Firefox. It seems like the only work-around is to add the `:hover` pseudo class to the parent `.btn` element `.btn:hover .fa-battery-full` - http://jsfiddle.net/nwkdvfp0/ Here is a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965810/buttonhover-not-working-in-firefox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add hover to your `btn` class:

```
.btn:hover {
    color:red;
}
```

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/w5anqozz/)

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for. Thanks a lot.